# How do you create a "function factory" in bash where the generated functions accepts its own command-line parameters?

Tags: bash

I love using the command-line tool [`howdoi`](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi). By default, it searches stackoverflow.com, but I also want to configure `howdoi` to search other StackExchange websites. According to [this comment](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi/issues/172#issuecomment-339378412), it is very easy to write a `bash` function to configure `howdoi` to search arbitrary StackExchange sites:

```
function howdoi-serverfault { HOWDOI_URL=serverfault.com howdoi $@; }
```

But it seems like this would be very hard to maintain because you have to write a function for every single StackExchange site you want to visit.

I thought about generalizing this pattern into a "function factory", so that it'd be easy to maintain if I want to search for new sites...

```
function howdoi-factory
{
  eval "
  function $1 {
      echo "Searching $2 for $@";
      HOWDOI_URL=$2 howdoi $@;
    }
  "
}

howdoi-factory howdoi-engineer softwareengineering.stackexchange.com
```

What I would expect the code to do:

```
> howdoi-engineer write good code
Searching softwareengineering.stackexchange.com for write good code
(answers relating to the keywords "write good code")
```

What I **actually** get:

```
> howdoi-engineer write good code
Searching softwareengineering.stackexchange.com for howdoi-engineer softwareengineering.stackexchange.com
(answers relating to the keywords "howdoi-engineer softwareengineering.stackexchange.com")
```

What would I need to do to ensure that my function factory would be able to generate functions that are able to accept command-line parameters of their own, instead of using reusing the "original" command-line parameters?

Comment: The most immediate problem here was caused by the use of double quotes, without escaping for the content you *didn't* want to be substituted. That said, if you only solved that initial problem and didn't also change to `printf %q`, you'd have security bugs wherein generating functions for malicious site names could be used to cause arbitrary code to be run on your system.

Comment: Also, **always** quote `"$@"`. When it's unquoted the arguments get split apart and glob-expanded, so for example a `'*'` would be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory despite its quoting.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd also tend to suggest making a habit of using POSIX rather than ksh function declaration syntax. It'd be different if using the ksh syntax, with the `function` keyword preceding and no `()` following the name, enabled the same extensions -- such as making variables local-by-default -- as it did in the ksh versions it's borrowed from, but that's not the case: in bash, this syntax just makes definitions incompatible with POSIX shells with no compensating advantage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `printf %q` format string to safely format data for inclusion in functions.

```
gen-howdoi() {
  local text
  for arg; do
    printf -v text 'howdoi-%q() { HOWDOI_URL=%q howdoi "$@"; }' "${arg%.*}" "$arg"
    eval "$text"
  done
}

# this creates howdoi-serverfault and howdoi-stackoverflow
gen-howdoi serverfault.com stackoverflow.com
```